# Email Template calling in the single email methos

Tags: email, template

I want to call Email template in single email method i am using the below code but this is not working.  the Query for email template is not working.please check this help will be more appreciated.

My code:

```
public class singleEmailExample{

public PageReference SendingEmail()
{

 EmailTemplate et=[Select id,developername, IsActive  from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Recruitmentemail_template'];


List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> email = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<string> ToEmailAddress = new List<string>();
mail.settoAddresses(new String[] {'mrachana93@gmail.com'}); 
mail.setSubject('US Departure Process -');
mail.setTemplateId(et.id);


email.add(mail);
mail.SetTemplateid(et.id);

Messaging.sendEmail(email);

return null;
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: if the soql isn't working, try it in DeveloperConsole to debug

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check in developer console, to paste this query.

'DeveloperName'='Recruitmentemail_template' is available or not.